# How to wildcard a filename when executing a wget in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've read through all the previous posts on this, tried the answers, none of which worked for me.

This works:

```
 ssh myuser@mynode.mydomain.com 'sudo wget --auth-no-challenge --http-password=xyz123 --http-user=jenkins -O /srv/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war http://jenkins.mydomain.com/job/mywebsite/job/master/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/mywebsite-1.13.5.0.war'
```

This does not:

```
 ssh myuser@mynode.mydomain.com 'sudo wget --auth-no-challenge --http-password=xyz123 --http-user=jenkins -A.war -l2 -O /srv/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war http://jenkins.mydomain.com/job/mywebsite/job/master/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/'
```

I've also tried -A ".war", which also does not work and other variations.

Anyone ever do this wildcarding successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question, per se, has no relation to Jenkins, or `ssh`, but is about `wget` proper.

As stated in [Recursive Download](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Download.html#Recursive-Download) manual, `wget` doesn't have any idea of what files are there on the web server, and it can't `ls -a` over http (and for all the good reasons, as it's not a good idea). What `wget` *can* do is get a page, read it, find any links in it, and do some stuff with the linked material. For example, it can open the linked pages and read them, too. This is referred to as "crawling".

One of the things `wget` can do is to skip any links to certain files, and download and save certain other files. This is useful if you want to fully crawl a website, but only care for `.jpg` images on it. So you can tell `wget` to fully crawl a site (reading and analyzing any `.html` files), but only save `.jpg` files to disk.

The reason `wget` doesn't do what you want is that there is probably no page that has plain old html links to all the artifacts. Maybe it's javascript, or something else.

You may want to either look into `rsync --include='*.war' --exclude="*"` or stash/unstash Jenkins functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins populates the artifact list with JavaScript, that's why wget's recursive download cannot work; there are no direct links to extract.

I would use API call to get list of interesting artifacts, then I would extract the name and use it for subsequent call, i.e.:

```
actual_file_name=$(curl -s -ujenkins:xyz123 http://jenkins.mydomain.com/job/mywebsite/job/master/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json | jq -r '[.artifacts[] | select(.fileName | endswith(".war")) | .relativePath] | first')
curl -s -ujenkins:xyz123 -o /srv/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war http://jenkins.mydomain.com/job/mywebsite/job/master/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/$actual_file_name
```

EDIT:

The same with `wget`:

```
actual_file_name=$(wget -q --auth-no-challenge --user jenkins --password xyz123 -O - http://jenkins.mydomain.com/job/mywebsite/job/master/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json | jq -r '[.artifacts[] | select(.fileName | endswith(".war")) | .relativePath] | first')
wget --auth-no-challenge --user jenkins --password xyz123 -O /srv/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war http://jenkins.mydomain.com/job/mywebsite/job/master/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/$actual_file_name
```